# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json Loop Through Multiple Files to Output to CSV

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have a folder with dozens of json files that I output to csv via powershell.  All the json files have the same format. My current powershell script is defining each file one by one by the file name, selecting various values and outputting it to the same csv.

How do I modify the powershell script so that it simply goes through each file in the folder without having to define each one by its file name specifically?

Each json's content is like this:

```
   {
      "ItemName": "A",
      "ItemID": "I001",
      "ItemDate": "2021-03-01",
      "ItemValue": "1000",
      "ItemTags": [
         {
            "Name": "Tag 1",
            "Value": "medium"
         },
         {
            "Name": "Tag 2",
            "Value": "red"
         },
         {
            "Name": "Tag 3",
            "Value": null
         },
         {
            "Name": "Tag 4",
            "Value": "Yes"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ItemName": "B",
      "ItemID": "I002",
      "ItemDate": "2021-02-01",
      "ItemValue": "3000",
      "ItemTags": [
         {
            "Name": "Tag 1",
            "Value": "best"
         },
         {
            "Name": "Tag 2",
            "Value": "green"
         },
         {
            "Name": "Tag 3",
            "Value": null
         },
         {
            "Name": "Tag 4",
            "Value": "No"
         }
      ]
```

Here's a sample of the powershell.  How do I modify it so goes through the C:\temp folder and do the same output for each file without the -Path part needing to be specified with the file name?

```
$obj1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\sample1.json"  | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj1 | select ItemName, ItemID, ItemDate, ItemValue, @{Name = 'Tag 4'; Expression ={($_.itemtags | where-object Name -eq "Tag 4").Value}} | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\items.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

$obj2 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\sample2.json"  | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj2 | select ItemName, ItemID, ItemDate, ItemValue, @{Name = 'Tag 4'; Expression ={($_.itemtags | where-object Name -eq "Tag 4").Value}} | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\items.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

$obj3 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\sample3.json"  | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj3 | select ItemName, ItemID, ItemDate, ItemValue, @{Name = 'Tag 4'; Expression ={($_.itemtags | where-object Name -eq "Tag 4").Value}} | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\items.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$properties = @(
    'ItemName', 'ItemID', 'ItemDate'
    'ItemValue', @{
        Name = 'Tag 4'
        Expression = {
            ($_.itemtags | Where-Object Name -eq "Tag 4").Value
        }
    }
)

Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -File -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_ -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object $properties
} | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\items.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

#### Edit

I reproduced the JSON from your example, if all JSONs look like this let me know and I'll edit my code.

```
PS \> $json[0]

ItemName  : A
ItemID    : I001
ItemDate  : 2021-03-01
ItemValue : 1000
ItemTags  : {@{Name=Tag 1; Value=medium}, @{Name=Tag 2; Value=red}, @{Name=Tag 3; Value=}, @{Name=Tag 4; Value=Yes}}

ItemName  : B
ItemID    : I002
ItemDate  : 2021-02-01
ItemValue : 3000
ItemTags  : {@{Name=Tag 1; Value=best}, @{Name=Tag 2; Value=green}, @{Name=Tag 3; Value=}, @{Name=Tag 4; Value=No}}

PS \> $json[0][0]

ItemName  : A
ItemID    : I001
ItemDate  : 2021-03-01
ItemValue : 1000
ItemTags  : {@{Name=Tag 1; Value=medium}, @{Name=Tag 2; Value=red}, @{Name=Tag 3; Value=}, @{Name=Tag 4; Value=Yes}}
```

#### Edit 2

```
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -File -Filter *.json

$result = foreach($json in $jsonFiles)
{
    $content = Get-Content $json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    foreach($element in $content)
    {
        $tag4 = $element.itemtags.where({$_.Name -eq "Tag 4"}).Value

        [pscustomobject]@{
            ItemName = $element.ItemName
            ItemID = $element.ItemID
            ItemDate = $element.ItemDate
            ItemValue = $element.ItemValue
            Tag4 = $tag4
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv "C:\temp\items.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't really work, I'm not getting any values from the output, just the column headings.

Comment: @wd510 I think I know why this happens, do all JSON files look like the one from your question? Because that JSON is creating an array of 2 items. See my edit for more details.

Comment: not sure I fully understand, but yes, all the json files look like what i posted, with nested arrays for the ItemTags value.

Comment: @wd510 I mean, do you see that each JSON has 2 elements, like in my example, you can see that the `$json` variable has 2 elements, one element is the one with `ItemName = A` and the second one is the one with `ItemName = B`.

Comment: yes, each json file actually has around 250 elements in each file and then about 45 json files total to loop through so I expect the csv output to have around 11k rows

Comment: @wd510 I see, ok I added `Edit 2` check it out. It is more code but much more efficient and should solve the issue you mentioned before. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: This is great, thanks for working through it

Comment: @wd510 no problem, happy to help!